# Not printing files content in socket programming

Tags: java, file, sockets, http

I am naive to this socket programming. I am trying to print the content of the file present in the directory in the server's console but the server is not able to locate the file.

Here is my code:

```
myClient.java


import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class myClient {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Socket socket = null;
        String hostName,command,fileName;
        int port;

        if(args.length == 0){
            System.out.println("Error: command line arguments (hostname,port,command,"
                    + "filename) not found.\nTry again...!!!");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        hostName = args[0];
        port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        command = args[2];
        fileName = args[3];

        try{
            socket = new Socket(hostName,port);
            System.out.println("Client Socket Created..!!");

            // creating input and output streams to read from and write to the server
            OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

            InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

            if(command.equals("GET")){

                System.out.println("Client: GET "+fileName+" HTTP/1.1\n");
                bw.write(fileName);

                String line = br.readLine();
                while(line != null){
                    System.out.println("Server: "+line);
                    line = br.readLine();
                }
            }
            if(command.equals("PUT")){
                System.out.println("Client: "+fileName+" sent to server");
                bw.write(fileName);
                // pass the file contents
                bw.flush();

                System.out.println("Server: "+br.readLine());
            }
        }
        catch(UnknownHostException uhe){
            System.out.println("Unknown Host...!!!");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            //Closing the socket
            try{
                socket.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}


myServer.java


import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class myServer {
    static Socket socket;
    public static void main(String args[]){
        try {
            int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            //String fileName = "";
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);

            while(true)
            {
                System.out.println("Server started and listening on port "+port);
                socket = server.accept();
                System.out.println("received a connection :"+socket);

                InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

                OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

                bw.write("Echo server 1.1\n");
                bw.flush();

                String line = br.readLine();
                while(line != null){
                    bw.write("Echo: "+line);
                    bw.flush();
                    line = br.readLine();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("No conncetion established");
            System.exit(0);
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            //Closing the socket
            try{
                socket.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Kindly help me out finding a solution to this. I have tried many examples browsing different websites but not get to the solutions.

Comment: What error are you getting? Please edit the error message and stack trace into the question.

Comment: Not getting any error or exceptions. I am trying to send a file from client and print its contents but this code of mine is not doing the same. I could be missing basic stuffs as I am completely trying new.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Client: GET "+fileName+" HTTP/1.1\n");
bw.write(fileName);
```

You aren't writing a correct HTTP command to the server. You're only sending the filename, not a complete command such as the GET command you're printing to the console.

The line terminator in HTTP is specified as `\r\n`, not `\n`.

You're also making no attempt to implement other aspects of HTTP 1.1 correctly, such as content-length. If you're going to implement HTTP you need a good knowledge of RFC 2616.

If possible you should throw this away and use `HttpURLConnection.`